# Сортировка LinkerHashMap

Tags: java, сортировка, map

Всех приветствую.
Возникла задача, с которой совладать не могу из-за болезни.
Прошу помощи.
Нужно сделать сортировку по фамильно (по алфавиту)
Код ниже прилагаю:

```
public class UserValuesGenerator implements ValuesGenerator {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserValuesGenerator.class);

  public Map getValues(Map args) {
    //TODO: output list with users is not sorted
    Map<String, String> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    ResultSet rs = null;
    SQLProcessor sqlProcessor = new SQLProcessor("defaultDS");
    try {
      sqlProcessor.prepareStatement(
          "SELECT cu.display_name, cu.user_name FROM cwd_user cu, cg_staff c "
          + "where c.jira_user_id = cu.id group by cu.display_name, "
          + "cu.user_name order by cu.display_name");
      sqlProcessor.executeQuery();
      rs = sqlProcessor.getResultSet();

      while (rs.next()) {
        result.put(rs.getString("user_name"), rs.getString("display_name"));
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    finally {
      UniversalCloser closer = new UniversalCloser();
      closer.close(rs);
      closer.close(sqlProcessor);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А зачем сортировать мапу, если данные возвращаются отсортированными из базы?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте TreeMap, он автоматически отсортирует вам мапу

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поменять запрос так

```
  sqlProcessor.prepareStatement(
      "SELECT * FROM (SELECT cu.display_name, cu.user_name FROM cwd_user cu, cg_staff c "
      + "where c.jira_user_id = cu.id group by cu.display_name, "
      + "cu.user_name) AS data ORDER BY order by data.display_name");
  sqlProcessor.executeQuery();
```